# Qt5 C++ resize font based on label width

Tags: c++, layout, qt5, qlabel

I have written what I think is a pretty good font resize algorithm that I use on labels in a QGridLayout. The algorithm works rather well on its own. However, the first time I run the algorithm, the layout hasn't been painted yet, and as such, the grid widgets which own the labels haven't been sized to the layout, which means my width() call is wrong, though I have assigned the label text prior to the resize (which doesn't matter). My question is, what is the best way to know the bounding rectangles have been created to fit the layout so my calculation is on the actual label width?

Note, this is Qt5.7, so I know that `fm.width()` is obsolete, but that's what's available in Raspbian.

My app is reading Sonos metadata and showing it on a 7" RPi display. I'm resizing the metadata that is too long to fit in the layout grids. So, I have a QStackedLayout with a set of layouts to show (clock when Sonos isn't playing, metadata when it is), and I frequently poll the a local Sonos server to find out if there is metadata to show. This works well. What doesn't happen is that on the first time the Sonos metadata layout is shown, the QGridLayout hasn't actually been laid out yet (I believe), so the labels are too big. At some point after the first time I fill in the metadata, the grid layout gets "shown" and the labels are then the correct size. The problem is, by then, it's all done setting metadata and the labels look funny in some cases.

```
    int pointSize = FontSize::Default;

    for (auto label : m_labels) {
        QFont f = label->font();

        if (label->accessibleName() == "title")
            pointSize = FontSize::Title;

        QFontMetrics fm(f);
        if (fm.width(label->text()) > label->width()) {
            float factor = (float)label->width() / (float)fm.width(label->text());
            if (factor <= .6) {
                factor = .6;
            }
            f.setPointSizeF((f.pointSize() * factor) * .9);
            qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << ": label width:" << label->width();
            qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << ": font width:" << fm.width(label->text());
            qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << ": Calculated font scaling factor to be" << (float)(factor * .9);
            qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << ": Reset font size for text\"" << label->text() << "\" to" << f.pointSize();
        }
        else
            f.setPointSize(pointSize);

        label->setFont(f);
    }
```

On an 800x480 display, this results in the first event label width being wrong

```
calculateLabelFontSize : label width: 640
calculateLabelFontSize : font width: 2051
```

The label width the next time it's called would end up being correct with a width of 584. However, because I don't always call it a second time, and because sometimes, the Sonos metadata hiccups and causes the display to revert, it may *always* be wrong, or it may just be right the first time no matter what.

I've considered trying to overload my gui app paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event), but the QPaintEvent class doesn't give me a way to determine which widget called for the event, so I can't just ignore the event until I want it. At least, not that I have determined, so if that's possible, please let me know.

I've tried overloading showEvent, but that doesn't run except when the frame is first shown, so no help there.

I've considered subclassing QGridLayout to simply overload the paintEvent() and use that, but I do have an issue with that solution. There is a progress bar in this layout, which means that the paintEvent is going to fire every half second as I get metadata from the Sonos server. Since I don't know if the paintEvent is firing for the time update, or for the text being set, I get a lot of resize attempts.

I've also simply run the algorithm a second time on the next event, but it's a really weird looking graphical hiccup when the fonts realign, and I don't like it.

Last up, I may just subclass QLabel, simply to overload paintEvent, and use that custom label just for the labels that would be resizable. However, is the label in the layout painted before or after the container it lives in inside the layout? I'll be testing this today I think, but I'm not convinced it would work.

I figure this has a much easier solution though. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried overriding [`resizeEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) and putting the font resizing logic in that?

Comment: I could do that, but no, I did not consider that. I think that might work , as the label would be resized. It would still have to be a subclass of QLabel though, and I wonder if I can do this without a custom class. I feel like Qt probably provides a mechanism that uses their own classes somehow.

Comment: Update on the resizeEvent logic. While that would work when the item is resized, it would not work for every text update when I need the resize to happen. That's because the label size is computed when the layout is painted, and not on every setText() event. So, it would resize the first time, but not the rest. I would need two resize implementations then, one for resizeEvent, and one for every setText event.

Comment: @G.M., I did what you suggested, and that seems to work pretty well. I still think there is an easier way to figure out when to resize the fonts, but this did work well, and didn't take very long to implement. Just subclass QLabel and overload resizeEvent. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm going to leave this open for now without a specific resolution because I still wonder if there is a better way to do it. If not, I'll add it as a solution and close in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I borrowed code from https://github.com/jonaias/DynamicFontSizeWidgets which provided the resize algorithm. It's nice, but iterative. I have been tinkering with a math based solution to calculate instead of just trying to fit by resizing until it works. However, that solution still doesn't work well enough to use. This isn't slow, and does what is implied. It resizes the font until it fits.

This all is done in paintEvent() because using resizeEvent() may result in either an infinite resize loop or the layout may resize itself and suddenly everything looks shifted/squished/stretched. Doing it in paintEvent means it's only called once every time you update the text, but not otherwise.

I may come back to this to try to find a math based solution. I still think this isn't the correct way, but I found something that worked well enough for now.

NewLabel.h

```
#ifndef NEWLABEL_H
#define NEWLABEL_H

#include <QtCore/QtCore>
#include <QtWidgets/QtWidgets>
#include <cmath>

class NewLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit NewLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());
    explicit NewLabel(QWidget *parent = nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());
    virtual ~NewLabel() {}

    void setDefaultPointSize(int p)
    {
        m_defaultPointSize = static_cast<float>(p);
    }
    
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) override;
    
private:
    float getWidgetMaximumFontSize(QWidget *widget, QString text);
    float m_defaultPointSize;
};

#endif
```

NewLabel.cpp

```
#define FONT_PRECISION (0.5)

NewLabel::NewLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags f) : QLabel(text, parent, f)
{
    m_defaultPointSize = 12;
}

NewLabel::NewLabel(QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags f) :
    QLabel(parent, f)
{
    m_defaultPointSize = 12;
}

void NewLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QFont newFont = font();
    float fontSize = getWidgetMaximumFontSize(this, this->text());
    if (fontSize < m_defaultPointSize) {
        newFont.setPointSizeF(fontSize);
        setFont(newFont);
    }
    QLabel::paintEvent(e);
}

float NewLabel::getWidgetMaximumFontSize(QWidget *widget, QString text)
{
    QFont font = widget->font();
    const QRect widgetRect = widget->contentsRect();
    const float widgetWidth = widgetRect.width();
    const float widgetHeight = widgetRect.height();

    QRectF newFontSizeRect;
    float currentSize = font.pointSizeF();

    float step = currentSize/2.0;

    /* If too small, increase step */
    if (step<=FONT_PRECISION){
        step = FONT_PRECISION*4.0;
    }

    float lastTestedSize = currentSize;

    float currentHeight = 0;
    float currentWidth = 0;
    if (text==""){
        return currentSize;
    }

    /* Only stop when step is small enough and new size is smaller than QWidget */
    while(step>FONT_PRECISION || (currentHeight > widgetHeight) || (currentWidth > widgetWidth)){
        /* Keep last tested value */
        lastTestedSize = currentSize;

        /* Test label with its font */
        font.setPointSizeF(currentSize);
        /* Use font metrics to test */
        QFontMetricsF fm(font);

        /* Check if widget is QLabel */
        QLabel *label = qobject_cast<QLabel*>(widget);
        if (label) {
            newFontSizeRect = fm.boundingRect(widgetRect, (label->wordWrap()?Qt::TextWordWrap:0) | label->alignment(), text);
        }
        else{
            newFontSizeRect = fm.boundingRect(widgetRect,  0, text);
        }

        currentHeight = newFontSizeRect.height();
        currentWidth = newFontSizeRect.width();

        /* If new font size is too big, decrease it */
        if ((currentHeight > widgetHeight) || (currentWidth > widgetWidth)){
            //qDebug() << "-- contentsRect()" << label->contentsRect() << "rect"<< label->rect() << " newFontSizeRect" << newFontSizeRect << "Tight" << text << currentSize;
            currentSize -=step;
            /* if step is small enough, keep it constant, so it converge to biggest font size */
            if (step>FONT_PRECISION){
                step/=2.0;
            }
            /* Do not allow negative size */
            if (currentSize<=0){
                break;
            }
        }
        /* If new font size is smaller than maximum possible size, increase it */
        else{
            //qDebug() << "++ contentsRect()" << label->contentsRect() << "rect"<< label->rect() << " newFontSizeRect" << newFontSizeRect << "Tight" << text << currentSize;
            currentSize +=step;
        }
    }
    return lastTestedSize;
}
```